# Error when using the UsageReportWithCSOM Script

Tags: powershell, error, onedrive-for-business

Just using your script to grab the OD4B usage details, when running the script I'm receiving below error each time it queries someone's URL. Any ideas? I'm running the script as an O365 Global Admin.

> an access denied and 401 unauthorized message

This is what it looks like for each OD4B site the script queries:

> Storage: Percentage used: Storage free:  1099511627776 Processing 
>   https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_tenantname_com
>   Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Access denied.
>   You do not have permission to perform this acti At
>   C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\UsageReportWithCSOM.ps1:56 char:3
>   +   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerUnauthorizedAccessException
>
> Percentage used: Storage free:  1099511627776 Processing 
>   https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_tenantname_com
>   Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote
>   server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." At
>   C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\UsageReportWithCSOM.ps1:52 char:3
>   +   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
>   +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Answer (score 1):

I see you are accessing personal sites of your users. Do you have access to them, e.g. when you paste in the browser  https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_tenantname_com?

If not, you can temporarily assign yourself as the site admin for the users, using

```
Set-SPOUser admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com -Site https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_tenantname_com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
```

For example:

```
$users=(Get-SPOUser -Site https://TENANT-my.sharepoint.com).LoginName
foreach($user in $users)
{

Set-SPOUser admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com -Site https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_tenantname_com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
}
```

Comment: I can access the  personal sites of your users. When  paste in the browser https://tenantname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_tenantname_com? and enter my credentials I can open their one drive files

Comment: What happens if you run Set-SPOUser for one of the affected sites and then try to pull the usage report for that site? Does it work? Does the error change?